# How to create a delegate to a target with variable number of arguments

Tags: c#, linq, delegates, lambda

Let's assume there is a method which takes a variable number of arguments:

```
void Target( params object[] args );
```

To attach this to an action with a concrete parameter list we can create a lambda expression:

```
Action<int, int> someAction += (a, b) => Target(a, b);
```

Is there a possibility to create this lambda expression dynamically to be able to attach the handler to any type of event? Something like:

```
someAction += CreateDelegate( typeof(someAction), Target );
```

I tried to use `Delegate.CreateDelegate` but it expects the target to provide a method with the concrete list of arguments. I have the feeling it should be possible with `Expression.Lambda` but for now I didn't have any success. Do you have an Idea?

**Edit**

Renamed event to action and handler to target.

Comment: Events should of course have exactly 2 parameters: sender and args.

Comment: @Henk Holterman INHO events can be Actions, too. It's possible to pass arguments directly and you don't need to pack them in an EventArgs objec. And how often do you use the sender object in a handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a look at the expressions behind the lambda by analyzing following line:

```
Expression<Action<int, int>> ex = (a, b) => Target(a, b);
```

Based on this I created an own delegate factory:

```
public static Delegate CreateDelegate( Type delegateType, Action<object[]> target )
{
    var sourceParameters = delegateType.GetMethod("Invoke").GetParameters();

    var parameters = sourceParameters.Select( p => Expression.Parameter( p.ParameterType, p.Name ) ).ToArray();

    var castParameters = parameters.Select(p => Expression.TypeAs(p, typeof(object))).ToArray();

    var createArray = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), castParameters);

    var invokeTarget = Expression.Invoke(Expression.Constant(target), createArray);

    var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda( delegateType, invokeTarget, parameters);

    return lambdaExpression.Compile();
 }
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

A delegate for this method:

```
void Handle( params object[] args );
```

Would be `Action<object[]>`, as delegates can not use the `params` modifier.  You would have to do what the compiler does, and map the other method into an object array.

The `params` keyword is handled by the compiler, so the runtime will use the method as if it just takes a normal object array.  In order to do this, you'd have to build an object array of the appropriate list, populate it with your objects, and then attach the method that does that to your handler.

Comment: Not quite - `Action<object[]>` doesn't have the `params` modifier, so you can't call it as `action(foo, bar, baz)` whereas a delegate which *really* had that signature *would* be callable that way.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! There is still the problem to map `Action<object[]>` to any other `Action< -something- >`. I need to do this dynamically. Maybe via Reflection?

Comment: @JonSkeet I edited to be more explicit, but that was kind of my point - delegates can't use the `params` modifier, so the OP would have to wrap the method call into an object array like within its calling method.